# How to find and get last childs from a javascript tree?

Tags: javascript, tree, parent-child

I want get all last nodes from a tree like this one, in this case i should  get all nodes like zona_urbana,franja_ejidal and something1, how i can do that? Thanks so much for any help!!

```
var o = 
    { "mexico": {
            "cancun": {
                "zona_urbana": "something",
                "franja_ejidal": "somehing"
            },
            "something1": "something"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you please post what you've tried so far?  The community will be more engaged and able to assist you if you provide the context of what work you've done towards solving this issue yourself first, as well as specific issues you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, getDeepKeys() will call recursively.

```
var o = 
    { "mexico": {
            "cancun": {
                "zona_urbana": "something",
                "franja_ejidal": "somehing"
            },
            "something1": "something"
        }
    }

function getDeepKeys(obj) {
    var keys = [];
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            var subkeys = getDeepKeys(obj[key]);
            keys = subkeys.map(function(subkey) {
                return subkey;
            });
        }
        else{
            keys.push(key);
        }
    }
    return keys; // ["zona_urbana", "franja_ejidal", "something1"]
}

getDeepKeys(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access object values by this way:

```js
var o = 
    { "mexico": {
            "cancun": {
                "zona_urbana": "something",
                "franja_ejidal": "somehing"
            },
            "something1": "something"
        }
    };

    console.log(Object.values(o));
```